# How to avoid redundancy with HTML code -- do not want same code for multiple html files

Tags: javascript, html, csv, d3.js

I have 4-5 html files that essentially read in csv files with D3.js and convert them into tables.  The problem is that each html file uses the exact same code, just reads a different csv file. So the one thing unique in the code for each .html is this one line:

```
d3.csv("../reservations/arc.csv", function(error, data)
```

I'm guessing this is not the only way going about doing this.  I apologize if my question is a little confusing..I'm not entirely sure if I have made it clear what I'm seeking exactly, but please let me know any clarifications needed.

Here is the layout of all the pages on the site:

[image: URL]

When I click on a link, the script should load the corresponding csv.

I'm assuming that I need to make a template with the code above and then pass a parameter into that line d3.csv(csv) but I am really not sure how. This is the easy way out, as I see it.

Here is what the index.html page looks like:

```
<head>
<title>AWS EC2 Instances</title>
 <script     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
  $("#includedContent").load("date.html");
});
    </script>
</head>
<html>
<h1>Show EC2 Instances, Owners & Reservation Status</h1>

<h2>Account</h2>
<ul>
    <li><a href="/resdisplay/arc.html">Arc</a> | <a href="/reservations/arc.csv">(Download CSV)</a></li>
    <li><a href="/resdisplay/coral.html">Coral</a> | <a href="/reservations/coral.csv">(Download CSV)</a></li>
    <li><a href="/resdisplay/dw.html">Data Warehouse</a> | <a href="/reservations/dw.csv">(Download CSV)</a></li>
    <li><a href="/resdisplay/elections.html">Elections</a> | <a href="/reservations/elections.csv">(Download CSV)</a></li>
    <li><a href="/resdisplay/enterprise.html">Enterprise</a> | <a href="/reservations/enterprise.csv">(Download CSV)</a></li>
    <li><a href="/resdisplay/inf.html">Inf</a> | <a href="/reservations/inf.csv">(Download CSV)</a></li>
    <li><a href="/resdisplay/main.html">Main</a> | <a href="/reservations/main.csv">(Download CSV)</a></li>
    <li><a href="/resdisplay/news.html">News</a> | <a href="/reservations/news.csv">(Download CSV)</a></li>
    <li><a href="/resdisplay/nile.html">Nile</a> | <a href="/reservations/nile.csv">(Download CSV)</a></li>
    <li><a href="/resdisplay/pci.html">Compliance (PCI)</a> | <a href="/reservations/pci.csv">(Download CSV)</a></li>
    <li><a href="/resdisplay/platform.html">Platform</a> | <a href="/reservations/platform.csv">(Download CSV)</a></li>
    <li><a href="/resdisplay/sandbox.html">Sandbox</a> | <a href="/reservations/sandbox.csv">(Download CSV)</a></li>
    <li><a href="/resdisplay/video.html">Video</a> | <a href="/reservations/video.csv">(Download CSV)</a></li>
</ul>
<p>
<div align="center">
```

I'm not too familiar with html/js, your help would be greatly appreciated.   Thanks!

EDIT - my question has branched:

Can I just create a separate .js file that creates the table (serves as the template) and then create a function within that js file, that takes a csv as a parameter? The function would essentially build the entire table template.

Comment: Pick a template language and either a server side programming language or a build time preprocessor to use it with.

Comment: PHP includes work like a charm for me.

Comment: How about reading the URL query, and loading the corresponding CSV in one HTML file?

Comment: @Nekomajin42 How would I do that? Would that require me to change the architecture of the workspace?

Comment: I've just posted a simple solution. You don't need to bother with the URL, it can handle it in-place.

Answer (score 1):

Attach a click listener to each 'download csv' anchor. Hand this.getAttribute("href") to the d3.csv method.

Comment: The problem with that is that the download csv does exactly that, it downloads the .csv.  The event listener would have to be attached to the button preceding 'Download CSV' button.  The href for that is the html file where as the href for the Download CSV is the path of the csv.

Comment: I edited my original question to include a snippet of the code from index.html.

Answer (score 0):

## First solution (in place)

```js
// collect every link with the .show class
var links = document.querySelectorAll(".show");
// bind an event listener to each
for (var i=0; i<links.length; i++)
{
    links[i].addEventListener("click", function(e)
    {
        // prevent default link behavior
        e.preventDefault();
        // get the path of the file
        var path = e.target.href;
        // use it
        d3.csv(path, function(error, data)
        {
            // insert code here to build the table
        });
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="show" href="dir/file1.csv">File 1</a> | <a class="download" href="dir/file1.csv">(Download File 1)</a></li>
    <li><a class="show" href="dir/file2.csv">File 2</a> | <a class="download" href="dir/file2.csv">(Download File 2)</a></li>
    <li><a class="show" href="dir/file3.csv">File 3</a> | <a class="download" href="dir/file3.csv">(Download File 3)</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="table">
  <!-- draw the table here -->
</div>
```

## Second solution (separate file)

```html
<!-- this goes to index.html -->

<ul>
    <li><a class="show" href="table.html?csv=file1" target="_blank">File 1</a> | <a class="download" href="dir/file1.csv">(Download File 1)</a></li>
    <li><a class="show" href="table.html?csv=file2" target="_blank">File 2</a> | <a class="download" href="dir/file2.csv">(Download File 2)</a></li>
    <li><a class="show" href="table.html?csv=file3" target="_blank">File 3</a> | <a class="download" href="dir/file3.csv">(Download File 3)</a></li>
</ul>



<!-- this goes to table.html -->

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<script>
// bind an event listener to run the script right after the page is loaded
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function()
{
  // get the whole query part of the URL
  var query = location.search;
  
  // strip the "?" char from the beginning
  query = query.slice(1);
  
  // check if there are multiple queries (make it foolproof)
  var queryArray = query.split("&");
  
  // check if there is a query with the "csv" property
  var file;
  for (var i=0; i<queryArray.length; i++)
  {
    // does it start with "csv="?
    if (queryArray[i].slice(0, 4) === "csv=")
    {
      // if it does, get the rest of the string
      file = queryArray[i].slice(4);
    }
  }
  
  // now you have the file name, let's create a path
  var path = "dir/"+file+".csv";
  
  // then build the table
  d3.csv(path, function(error, data)
  {
    // insert code here to build the table
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I see. This would work well, however I do need to have those tables to be generated on a separate html.  I've edited my original question to show you my index.html page. The event listener must be on the first button, but href for that button is just the html page.  How could I attach the file path?

Comment: You can do it using the query part of the URL. Take a look at the edited answer.

Comment: I don't understand how I use table.html for the separate .html files.  Is table.html a file that I create and place in the directory of where index.html is? For example, when i click on 'Arc' is the work being done from table.html or am I supposed to call the script from table.html into arc.html?

Comment: You have your menu (list of files on your picture) in `index.html`. Pay attention to the snippet in my post! When you click on a link, `table.html` will open in a new tab. Once it is loaded, the script will parse the query part of the URL (after the question mark), and load the corresponding CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code, which does not require server side code. The key is pass the file name to the d3 html page using query string.

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<ul>
  <li><a href="resdisplay/display.html?name=arc">Arc</a> | <a href="/reservations/arc.csv">(Download CSV)</a></li>
  <li><a href="resdisplay/display.html?name=coral">Coral</a> | <a href="/reservations/coral.csv">(Download CSV)</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- display.html -->
<script>
    // Get file name from the query string
    function getParameterByName(url, name) {
        if (!url) url = window.location.href;
        name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
        var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
            results = regex.exec(url);
        if (!results) return null;
        if (!results[2]) return '';
        return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }
    
    var fileName = getParameterByName(window.location.href, "name");    
    d3.csv("../reservations/" + fileName + ".csv", function(error, data) { ... });
    
</script>
```